# How to host/setup an Angular 4 App on a local system of another Desktop?

Tags: angular

I have an application which has two parts:

1. JAVA Component (Listens on REST API)
2. Angular 4 App (on local machine. Sends API requests to JAVA and shows its response to the UI)

Now the intention is to share the same two components to another Desktop and run it locally.

I was able to do migrate the JAVA Component to a colleague's Desktop and its working fine. But as I have never done the same thing for Angular its a bit of a struggle right now and would appreciate help.

Things I'd need clarity on:

1. As a prerequisite, will installing just Node on the other system work? In our workplace its equivalent to adding node's directory to User variables. Is there any other way to make it work without adding it to User's Path?
2. After I had copied the entire project folder to my colleague's Desktop, what other steps would I need to run the project? Will 'npm start' in the project directory work? Intention is to just run the Angular Project locally. Colleague wont be Developing the project and will be just using the app.

Please let me know if there's any confusion.

Comment: Typically, you get an Angular app over the web. No need to install anything on the target machine (except a browser of course). The components would be hosted on a central server.

Comment: Agreed. But in this case it should be on a local system (atleast at this moment). I couldn't find any related content and that's why went ahead with this question.

Comment: So basically make the local system the server. Almost any web server can be configured to serve an Angular app. You can also used a node based server. Using development mode (`npm start`) would work, but is not the best solution since it is slower than it needs to be.